# Are these women “for sale in the market in Libya”?

Tags: africa, slavery, libya

[This post](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=256698898249039&id=125811591337771&refid=52&__tn__=-R) has been shared 142,000 times.

[image: women bound by hands and feet]

The associated text reads:

> Women for sale in the market in Libya, we are against slave trade. If you are against slave trade Share

Are these women in Libya, are they for sale in a market, and are they for sale as slaves?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80558/discussion-on-question-by-tim-are-these-women-for-sale-in-the-market-in-libya).

Answer (score 4):

> Are these women in Libya

Probably not in Libya.

> are they for sale in a market, and are they for sale as slaves?

Maybe.

The oldest version (June 26, 2018) I can find with reverse image search [yields an ivory coast paper](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.rumeursdabidjan.net/actualites/cote-d-ivoire/item/9874-des-filles-vendues-comme-esclaves-par-un-reseau-d-ivoiriennes-de-graves-revelations&prev=search) that claims women are sold by a network of Ivorians trafficked by women based in Abidjan and sold by Kuwaitis to Kuwaiti families with no mention of Libya.

I've found the claimed location attributed to Kuwait in some twitter posts but with no sourcing.

It seems to have taken off in the last week after turning up on some right wing sites with the Libya attribution.

I can't find it on any news website other than rumeursdabidjan, just twitter, facebook and blogs.

Comment: It doesn't say that the picture is from Ivory Coast.  It says: "All these girls you see have been sold as slaves by a network of Ivorians....Soon I will publish the names of some women based in Abidjan who do this trafficking". Also says that the girls are later sold by Kuwaitis to Kuwaiti families.  The location of the photo is not stated.

Comment: @DavePhD You're right. I'll edit to correct. It doesn't give a clear location. That might explain the various attributions re: Kuwaitis, Abidjan and Ivorians.

Comment: The rope doesn't look like it's actually knotted to any of the woman, just looped around their wrists and ankles. That suggests this is a posed photo. Perhaps a demonstration?

Comment: @Drew Isn't it tied around the girl on our right's neck? and with the gun just behind their heads, how tight do the ropes have to be?